# Accessing clicked cell instead of all cells using JQuery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I am trying to edit a specific cell once it's clicked. When I click a cell currently it turns all the `td` into textboxes. I would like only the clicked cell do that. How can I access just the clicked cell? Here is my current code: (ignore the `.change` function for now; I haven't fixed it yet.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".edit_td").click(function()
        {
            $(this).children(".text").hide();
            $(this).children(".editbox").show();
        }).change(function()
            {
                var id=$(this).parent();
                var field=$("#input_"+ id).val();
                var text=$("#span_" + id).val();
                var dataString = 'id='+ id +'&field='+ field +'&text='+ text;
                //$("#first_"+ID).html('<img src="load.gif" />'); // Loading image

                if(input != text)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "table_edit_ajax.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        $("#first_"+ID).html(first);
                        $("#last_"+ID).html(last);
                    }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Enter something.');
                }
            });

        // Edit input box click action
        $(".editbox").mouseup(function() 
        {
            return false
        });

        // Outside click action
        $(document).mouseup(function()
        {
            $(".editbox").hide();
            $(".text").show();
        });

    });
```

This is my PHP code:

```
   public function displayTable($table)
{
    //connect to DB
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

    echo "<table id='table' border='1'>";   //start an HTML table

    $dbtable = $table;
    $fields =array();
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$dbtable);

    //fill fields array with fields from table in database
    while ($x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $fields[] = $x['Field'];
    }

    $fieldsnum = count($fields);    //number of fields in array

    //create table header from dbtable fields
    foreach ($fields as $f)
    {
        echo "<th>".$f."</th>";
    }

    //create table rows from dbtable rows
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM ".$dbtable);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rowid = $row[$fields[0]];
        echo "<tr class='edit_tr' id='".$rowid."'>";
        foreach ($fields as $f) 
        { 
            echo "<td class='edit_td'><span id='span_".$rowid."' class='text'>".$row[$f]."</span>
            <input type='text' value='".$row[$f]."' class='editbox' id='input_".$rowid."'/> </td>"; 
        }
        $rowid++;
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";    //close the HTML table

    //close connection
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: You need to use DOM traversal functions to select the editbox associated with the element you clicked on. http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: You mention the clicked cell, but your click handler is bound to the entire row, not individual cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently telling ALL `text` and `editbox` to hide and show respectively whenever you click something. What you want to do is ONLY make the one related to the element you are clicking hide and show.

To do that, you will want to do something along the lines of

```
$(".edit_tr").click(function() {
    $(this).children(".text").hide();
    $(this).children(".editbox").show();
}) // your normal stuff can go here.
```

This will grab and modify ONLY the children of the class `edit_tr` and show/hide the items you want.

Comment: Thanks! I added that and just changed the `tr` to `td` and it works!

Comment: Now I am realizing that for my AJAX update I am going to have to 
get the ID (primary key) of that row. I am assuming I somehow utilize `.siblings()` or one of the other tree traversals to get
 to the first `td` in the `tr` of the `td` that was altered, right?

Comment: If you want the id of the `tr`, you can just do `$(this).parent()`, from there you can get whatever data is on the tr.

Comment: Well it isn't the id of the `tr`. I am looking for the first piece of data (`td`) in the `tr` of the `td` that was clicked. Though I suppose I could set the `tr` id to the primary key of the corresponding row in the database.

Comment: I changed my code in the original question to reflect what I now have. I made changes to the `while` loop in PHP and some changed to the `.changed` function in JQuery. How can I get the `var field` and `var text` to reflect my changes? I currently have the `var id` set to the id of the corresponding row in the database.

For instance, I would like the `var field` to hold the field name I am changing and the `var text` to hold the new value to place in that field once it is `POST`ed to PHP code to send the update query to the database. Thanks.

Comment: Also, how can I access the `id` of the `tr` since it's a variable? How do I set that inside `.parent()`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `this` object.

```
$(this).find(".text").hide();
$(this).find(".editbox").show();
```

It will access current row rather than all of `td` of your code.

Comment: i think you are posting on wrong answer, you have selected other answer as right one :-)