# JQuery .ajax() post to php database query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I see a lot of questions like this, however, I am having trouble even getting into the .ajax() function. I had a previous issue resolved here: [Accessing clicked cell instead of all cells using JQuery and Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805918/accessing-clicked-cell-instead-of-all-cells-using-jquery-and-ajax/18805970?noredirect=1#comment27735805_18805970)
 My follow-up was never responded to, though. Instead of posting code again I'll leave it there (unless told otherwise). Can anyway help me figure out 1: get the `var field` and `var text` to reflect my changes. and 2: how to access the `id` of the `tr` since it's a variable. How do I set that inside .parent()? Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".edit_td").click(function()
        {
            $(this).children(".text").hide();
            $(this).children(".editbox").show();

        }).change(function()
            {
                alert("working");
                var id=$(this).parent();
                var field=$("#input_"+ id).val();
                var text=$(this).children(".editbox").val();

                var dataString = 'id='+ id +'&field='+ field +'&text='+ text;
                //$("#first_"+ID).html('<img src="load.gif" />'); // Loading image

                if(input != text)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "table_edit_ajax.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        $("#first_"+ID).html(first);
                        $("#last_"+ID).html(last);
                    }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Enter something.');
                }
            });

        // Edit input box click action
        $(".editbox").mouseup(function() 
        {
            return false
        });

        // Outside click action
        $(document).mouseup(function()
        {
            $(".editbox").hide();
            $(".text").show();
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Here is my php to display the table:

```
public function displayTable($table)
{
  //connect to DB
  $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

echo "<table id='table' border='1'>";   //start an HTML table

$dbtable = $table;
$fields =array();
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$dbtable);

//fill fields array with fields from table in database
while ($x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $fields[] = $x['Field'];
}

$fieldsnum = count($fields);    //number of fields in array

//create table header from dbtable fields
foreach ($fields as $f)
{
    echo "<th>".$f."</th>";
}

//create table rows from dbtable rows
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM ".$dbtable);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rowid = $row[$fields[0]];
    echo "<tr class='edit_tr' id='".$rowid."'>";
    foreach ($fields as $f) 
    { 
        echo "<td class='edit_td'><span id='span_".$rowid."' class='text'>".$row[$f]."</span>
        <input type='text' value='".$row[$f]."' class='editbox' id='input_".$rowid."'/> </td>"; 
    }
    $rowid++;
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";    //close the HTML table

//close connection
mysqli_close($con);
```

}

I am not even sure I'm getting into my `.change()` function, but once I do I'd like to set `var id` to the row id which corresponds to my database id (which will allow me to run my update query by my primary key). The next thing id like to do is set `var field` to the column header of the `td` selected so I know what field from my database to select. The next thing i'd like is my `var text` to reflect the changed text from the textbox to send to the update query.

Now, I'd like to be able to send that to table_edit_ajax.php as a `POST` and run my update query. I am just really confused as to how to do all of that. I am very new to ajax and javascript, obviously.

EDIT: file: table_edit_ajax.php

```
<?php
//connect to DB
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

echo 'in table_edit';

$id = mysqli_escape_String($con, $_POST['id']);
$table = "owners";
$field = $_POST['field'];
$text = mysqli_escape_String($con, $_POST['text']);
$query = "UPDATE owners SET ".$field."='".$text."' WHERE id = '".$id."'";
mysqli_query($con, $query);

//close connection
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: nothing understandable from your prev question, paste your code and fiddle here,

Comment: Thanks, I edited it to reflect a more elaborated question.

Comment: please made fiddle, you overcomplicated thing for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're going to want to bind your change event to your input box, not its parent td, since I assume you want your function to run only when the input value changes. You'll also want to change the td binding from click to mouseup and add a stopPropagation call to avoid triggering the mouseup event on your document.

```
$(".edit_td").mouseup(function(e)
        {
            $(this).children(".text").hide();
            $(this).children(".editbox").show();
            e.stopPropagation();

        }).children('.editbox').change(function() {
```

To get the id of the tr:

```
var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
```

To get the text:

```
var text = $(this).val();
```

And the best way to go about getting the field is probably to assign a data attribute to your input box that represents the column header. In your PHP, as you're generating your tds:

```
foreach ($fields as $f) 
{ 
    echo "<td class='edit_td'><span id='span_".$rowid."' class='text'>".$row[$f]."</span>
    <input type='text' value='".$row[$f]."' class='editbox' id='input_".$rowid."' data-field='".$f."'/> </td>"; 
}
```

Then in your Javascript:

```
var field = $(this).data('field');
```

Furthermore, your query string may not be encoded correctly. It's best to provide the data as an object: eg. `{id:id, field:field, text:text}`, and let jQuery handle the url encoding for you.

And just a heads up, I noticed you're setting the id of your spans to `$rowid`. In doing this, your span id's will not be unique and may present a problem down the line. If you need to give them an id, try something like `id='span_".$rowid."."-".$f."'`.

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes and places this after the `var dataString`:

`document.write("<label>" + dataString + "</label>");` And I am not seeing anything displayed. The alert doesn't work, either. I assume this means that the function isn't running, right?

Comment: The change event should trigger as soon as the textbox loses focus.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. No luck, though.

Comment: Just to clarify. You click on the td, a textbox replaces the span. You change the value of the textbox, remove focus from the textbox, and nothing happens?

Comment: Actually, no. Once the span is clicked the text box replaces it then once the text box loses focus the original span replaces the text box. It's after that when nothing happens.

Comment: It actually does work. I just realized at some point I started editing a separate instance I had of the file! Wow...

Comment: I am still having trouble posting the data, though.

Comment: Thanks, but now after changing that my click event has stopped working. (I no longer get a textbox when the `td` is clicked).

Comment: Your click event on the td is likely bubbling up to the mouseup event on document.  Updated the answer again.

Comment: Each one is not meant to be unique. They reflect the id of the record in the database. Each row has different id, however, each `td` in the `tr` has the same id. Now, I managed to make it work. My only problem now is with my php. For some reason the query is not updating the database. I have updated my question to display the `table_edit_ajax.php` file.

Comment: But that's obtained through the id of the <tr>, why would you need to have that on the span as well? Either way, id attributes are meant to be unique, so if you're not going to add the field to it, at least set it as a class instead. As for the database portion, I recommend asking that in a separate question since your original issue has been resolved.